# Why Array's have a given property length, why it's not in prototype?

Tags: javascript, properties, prototype

Hello I've learned that inheritance happens with prototypes. What I don't understand is, let's say: we create a simple array

```
const arr = [2, 4];
```

Now, why is `Array.hasOwnProperty('length');` returns `true` here. The `length` property should be inherited therefore it should be in the prototype not in its own properties.
Why `length` is a exception here?

Comment: `The legth property should be inherited` No, it's directly on the object (the array instantiation), not on the prototype.

Comment: So all arrays have the same length? (Hint: no they don't)

Comment: `length` property most be on the instance, because array has its own length (depends on the items within it)

Comment: Because That’s Just The Way It Is™. It could have been a getter/setter combo on the prototype as far as I can tell, but it’s not. Instead, it’s magic. ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯ (I guess from an ES3 perspective it makes no sense for that kind of magic to be on the prototype, and by the time ES5 rolls around it has to continue being the case that `[].hasOwnProperty('length')`.)

Comment: Thank you all, it really helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every array has its own `length` property because every array could have a different length. Even though all arrays have one, it's not an inherited method (because it's not a method at all), and it's not an inherited getter/setter either, it's a magic property created during construction of the array instance.